# How to marshal c++ struct in c#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

Below is the C++ struct. Its implementation is done in a C++ DLL:

```cpp
typedef char CusDate[sizeof("2023-02-02")];

typedef enum cycletype {
    NOES=0,
    LET=1, 
    WARN=2,
    GRACE=3,
    EXP=4,
} MYCYCLETYPE;

typedef struct Info {
    MYCYCLETYPE midcycle;
    int  type;
    int porotype;
    long sways;
    CusDate sedate;            
    long days;
    CusDate elate;
    long edays;
    CusDate edate;
    const char* feature;
    const char* ver;
    const char* hid;
}SINFO, *SINFO;

int Initialize(SINFO lp)
{
    lp->mycycle = NOES;
    ......
    .....
    lp->hid = "XYZ";
}
```

Now, below is the C# code:

```cs
[DllImport(@"abc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int Initialize(ref SINFO lp);
```

In C# `main()`:

```cs
SINFO mydata;
Initialize(ref mydata);
```

Now, I am unable to access the struct data filled by C++ code in C#.
How to access the C++ struct data in C#?

Comment: You haven't shown how `SINFO` is defined on the C# side.

Comment: @wohlstad Isn't the OP asking how to do just that?

Comment: *Now, I am unable to access the struct data filled by C++ code in C#* -- I am curious at to how you populated those `char *` members from C++.  Even if you were able to access that stuct in C#, I wouldn't be surprised if those members turn out to have garbage on the C# side.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm not sure. They mention they were _"unable to access the data"_. I thought it was a runtime isssue and therefore the code passed compilation and SINFO must be defined. I may have misundertstood.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by _"unable to access ..."_ ? Is it a runtime issue or a matter of missing code ? Please [edit] your question and add all the relevant info including error messages (if relevant).

Comment: @wohlstad how to marshal the structure members and access the correct structure members value in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```cpp
> typedef struct Info {
>     ...
> } SINFO, *SINFO;
> ```

The above declaration is not valid C/C++, as you can't have the same identifier (`SINFO`) refer to two different types (`Info` and `Info*`). Perhaps you meant something more like this instead:

```cpp
typedef struct Info {
    ...
} SINFO, *PSINFO;
          ^
```

Or, the more C++-ish style (as the above style originates from C):

```cpp
struct SINFO {
    ...
};
typedef SINFO* PSINFO;
// or: using PSINFO = SINFO*;
```

Either way, `Initialize()` can then take either a `SINFO&` reference or a `PSINFO` pointer as its parameter, either of which would be compatible with `ref SINFO` on the C# side:

```cpp
int Initialize(SINFO& lp)
```

```cpp
int Initialize(PSINFO lp)
```

Where the C# code would look something like this:

```cs
public enum MYCYCLETYPE {
    NOES = 0,
    LET = 1, 
    WARN = 2,
    GRACE = 3,
    EXP = 4,
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  
public struct SINFO {
    public MYCYCLETYPE midcycle;
    public int type;
    public int porotype;
    public long sways; // <-- or int, depending on the C++ compiler!
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=11)]
    public byte[] sedate = new byte[11];
    // alternatively:
    // [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=11, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    // public String sedate;
    public long days; // <-- or int, depending on the C++ compiler!
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=11)]
    public byte[] elate = new byte[11];
    // alternatively:
    // [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=11, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    // public String elate;
    public long edays; // <-- or int, depending on the C++ compiler!
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=11)]
    public byte[] edate = new byte[11];
    // alternatively:
    // [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=11, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    // public String edate;
    public IntPtr feature; // <-- use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() to read this
    // alternatively:
    // [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    // public String feature;
    public IntPtr ver; // <-- use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() to read this
    // alternatively:
    // [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    // public String ver;
    public IntPtr hid; // <-- use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() to read this
    // alternatively:
    // [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    // public String hid;
};

[DllImport("abc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int Initialize(ref SINFO lp);
```

---

Also, on a side note: you have `Initialize()` declared as returning an `int`, but the C++ code you have shown is not actually `return`'ing a value, which is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: In c++ code

int Initialize(SINFO lp)
{
    lp->mycycle = NOES;
    ......
    .....
   <here assigning the values in each struct members>
    lp->hid = "XYZ";
    return 1;
}

Comment: I have declared the above struct in and called Initialize() in C#. Now, how to marshal each struct member and access the data in C#?

Comment: @lebeausoftware -the value assigned to const char * is getting changed in c++.Now, when we marshal the IntPtr how do we determine the length of string in c#.

Comment: @Indrasen the same way you do in C++ - by counting characters until you reach the null terminator. Let `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` handle that for you.

Comment: SINFO lp;
int result = Initialize(ref SINFO lp);

string feature = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(lp.feature); 
Console.WriteLine(feature);  --> Print nothing
 Console.WriteLine(lp.midcycle);  --> It is not printing the value assigned by Initialize()
 Console.WriteLine(lp.type); --> It is not printing the value assigned by Initialize()

Am i doing any thing wrong here?

Comment: Did you verify that the size, alignment, and padding of `SINFO` in C# matches the same size, alignment, and padding of `SINFO` in C++? If they don't match exactly, you won't get the correct results. Does the C++ code use 4 or 8 byte alignment for the struct? What is the size of `cycletype` and `long` in C++? They may be 1-or-4 and 4-or-8 bytes, respectively, depending on compiler settings. What value does C++'s `sizeof()` return for `SINFO`, and `offsetof()` return for each member of `SINFO`?

Comment: I have verified the alignment and size of each member of structure in both c++ and c# at my end. It seems good to me. I am currently compiling the c++ code in 64bit and similarly compiling the c# code in 64bit only.

Comment: Can you please give an example to marshal the structure members w.r.t above provided structure in c#?

Comment: "*I have verified the alignment and size of each member of structure in both c++ and c#*" - but, did you also verify the **byte offsets** of each member within the struct? Worse case, you *might* need to use [`[FieldOffset]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute?view=net-7.0) on the C# side. If everything lines up perfectly, then the code provided should work. Also make sure to verify that the memory address you are assigning to `feature`/`ver`/`hid` on the C++ side is the same numeric value that the `IntPtr`s receive on the C# side.

Comment: "*Can you please give an example to marshal the structure members w.r.t above provided structure in c#?*" - I already have.

Comment: string myfeature = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(lp.feature); 
Console.WriteLine(myfeature);--> Prints 133760539264 

It should print the some string value but it is printing some garbage

Comment: @Indrasen given the C++ code you have provided, that is the correct C# code (unless you switch to `MarshalAs` that I showed). So, what you describe can only happen if `lp.feature` is NOT receiving the correct memory address from C++ (I told you to verify that). Which means your `SINFO` record in C# DOES NOT exactly match up with `SINFO` in C++. There is something that is still off. You need to find and fix that. You claim that you have verified alignment/offsets, but I don't think you really have (and you haven't provided the **numbers** I asked you for), otherwise this would be working fine.

Comment: I have verified the alignment. It seems that in c++ DLL, the values for all structure members are not set. i.e out of 12 structure members values are set for only 5 structure members.

Comment: @Indrasen You haven't shown the complete C++ code, nor provided the actual numbers I've asked you for (several times), so I can't help you further until you do so. What you describe does not make sense given the code available so far, so there is still something missing.